# Backbone.Wreqr vs Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, eventaggregator

What are the main benefits **backbone.wreqr** has over a js **object**, both cases having access to marionette's Event aggregator.
Wouldn't assigning/calling methods from an object work the same way as Commands / RequestResponse. To me i see no need to implement this other than giving semantic/readability a +1.

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.wreqr
Can someone please enlighten me, this is my first backbone (and modular) application.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The benefits are:

- event and command handling is optional and you don't need to check manually yourself for `undefined`s
- optionally multiple handlers for each event
- lazy execution of commands (fire event first, register command later and it will immediately be executed)
- you can define the scope of execution w/o using any additional methods like `$.proxy`, ...

Comment: Thanks, Just what i was looking for! Point #1, so if no handler is present no errors will be thrown when commands.execute("blackhole") is triggered?

Answer (score 8):

It provides implementations of several common [messaging patterns](http://www.eaipatterns.com/), including the [Event Aggregator Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html), [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), and [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish/subscribe).

These patterns facilitate decoupling of implementations to reduce object dependencies. Consider a simple "Combat" style game consisting of a tank and several targets. Without messaging patterns, the tank needs to have explicit knowledge about the targets and how they work, and in fact cannot exist without the `target` definition:

```
var Tank = function(targets) { this.targets = targets };
Tank.prototype.fire = function() {
    var self = this,
        HpLoss = -500;
    _.each(this.targets, function(target) {
    if (self.isNear(target.coordinates) && target.canWithstand(HpLoss)) {
          target.die();
    }
}


var target1 = new Target(coordinatesA, armorA);
var target2 = new Target(coordinatesB, armorB);
var tank = new Tank([target1, target2]);
```

Using messaging patterns such as Observer, `tank` in the code above doesn't need knowledge of its targets; rather, the targets can determine for themselves whether they should die:

```
var Target = function() {}
Target.prototype.calculateDamage = function(coordinates, damage) {
    if (this.isNear(coordinates) && !this.canWithstand(damage)) {
        this.die();
    }
}

var Tank = function() {};
Tank.prototype.fire = function() {
    this.trigger('fire', { damage: 400, coordinates: this.location });
};

// Now Tank is entirely self-contained, and some external mediator can 
// make things happen at will:

function main() {
    var target1 = new Target(coordinatesA, armorA);
    var target2 = new Target(coordinatesB, armorB);
    var tank = new Tank();

    target1.listenTo(tank, 'fire', target1.calculateDamage, target1);
    target2.listenTo(tank, 'fire', target2.calculateDamage, target2);

    tank.fire();

    var target3 = new Target3(coordinatesB, armorB);
    target3.listenTo(tank, 'fire', target3.calculateDamage, target3);
}
```

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for the reply, though it does not answer my initial question. Your example is revealing the Subscriber / Publisher workflow contained in Event Aggregator. Wreqr's Commands / RequestResponse is what loses me, until clarification those methods exist solely for semantic / readability reasons.

Comment: This is a terrific comment however.